# How does the rotational plane sweep algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm

I have the task to implement the creation of a visibility graph based on a set of simple polygons which are given by the task. The polygons have positive whole number coordinates and can be non-convex. I wanted to implement the rotational plane sweep algorithm which was mentioned in the lecture but not very well explained.

The only other source I could find about this algorithm was this page, that did not make it fully clear either: https://tanergungor.blogspot.com/2015/04/robot-navigation-rotational-sweep.html

I would appreciate it if someone could explain the rotational plane sweep algorithm to an extent which I can understand.

Here is a screenshot of an example obstacle arrangement with my attempt at a solution which is not yet working and more or less based on trial and error rather than understanding and implementing the actual algorithm. The algorithm is just using a single vertex which is not located on a polygon in this example.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the goal more clearly? What do you mean by visibility graph precisely, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve something like this: https://fribbels.github.io/shortestpath/Images/vis1.png where my implementation should return a list of all edges which belong to the unreduced visibility-graph